# Where am I going wrong in finding the center of mass of this sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, integration, moment-of-inertia

A solid sphere of density $ρ$ and radius $R$ is centered at the origin. It has a spherical cavity in it that is of radius $R/4$ and which is centered at $(R/2, 0, 0)$, i.e. a small sphere of material has been removed from the large sphere. What is the the center of mass $R_{cm} = (x_{cm}, y_{cm}, z_{cm})$ of the large sphere, including the cavity?

**My attempt:**

$$\vec{R}=\frac{1}{M}\int \vec{r}dm$$

$M=\rho V=\rho (V_{total}-V_{cavity})=$total mass

$\vec{r}=x^2\hat x + y^2 \hat y+z^2 \hat z$

$dm= \rho dV$

$$\vec{R}=\frac{1}{\rho (V_{total}-V_{cavity})}\int_V \rho (x^2\hat x + y^2 \hat y+z^2 \hat z)dV$$

$$=\frac{1}{ (V_{total}-V_{cavity})}\int_0^x \int_0^y \int_0^{\sqrt{R-x^2-y^2}}  (x^2\hat x + y^2 \hat y+z^2 \hat z)dxdydz$$

...but here I'm confused - how do I set up the integral to account for the cavity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont have to complicate using such integrals. Just do this. Assume the larger sphere to be complete and find its centre of mass (which is its geometrical centre of course). Now for the cavity, assume it is made of negative mass(no such thing of course, just eases the calculation).The mass of the smaller sphere would then be $-M/64$ (where $M$ is the mass of the larger sphere) Find its centre of mass co-ordinates. Then use the formula for the centre of mass for two point masses located at two points(which are the co-ordinates of the centre of mass of larger sphere and that of the smaller sphere/cavity) giving $R_{COM}$ = $(-\frac{R}{126},0,0)$

Comment: Ok so it seems as though we can pretend that the entire mass of both the sphere and the negatively massed cavity are located at their centers. This entire method seems to be based on this concept. Why is this ok to do though?

Comment: What's stopping us? To account for the cavity, we are putting an equal amount of positive and negative mass proportional to its volume. Just to mention it again, there is no such thing as negative mass. It is only a simple way to solve the problem

Comment: Right, the negative mass is just a mathematical trick. But doesn't the size/shape of the spheres have any effect on the outcome? There is a considerable difference between a point mass and a sphere with mass and I don't quite logically see how we can say that all of the mass rests at the center. I can see how the symmetry of the problem helps, but I don't see the rigid argument for this.

Comment: If it is a perfect sphere, then the geometrical centre IS the centre of mass. Why do you have trouble seeing that? Just look at it this way. For a sphere, consider a diameter with two infinitesimal equal masses at its ends. Where do you think its centre of mass would be? Of course at the centre. Now extrapolate that argument to all the possible diameters and after you are done, reduce the diameter by an infinitesimal length again repeat the process....why would the centre of mass be anywhere else except at the centre? This kind of argument goes for all symmetrical uniform density bodies